# Translation of "the asker"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Sometimes when I have to refer to the poster of a question in this site, in English I can use *the asker* as it seems it is [the most used word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/124346/98507), at least here. But what if I want to refer to the asker in Spanish? I usually write my sentence like this:

> El que pregunta conoce la diferencia entre...

O even like this, to hide any possible reference to a specific gender (el/la):

> Quien pregunta conoce la diferencia entre...

Nonetheless, I would like to know if there is any noun I can use in Spanish, registered in the *DLE*, that conveys the meaning of 'someone who has asked a question', something like *el [preguntador](https://dle.rae.es/-or)* or *el [inquiriente](https://dle.rae.es/-nte)* (links to the proper suffixes used for both cases), that may be valid words but sound a bit strange to me. Leaving aside the debate about trying not to assume a gender for the asker, does such a word exist in Spanish?

Comment: I suppose _inquisidor_ would be too specialised.

Comment: @mdewey in fact "inquisidor" is a good answer if you look up its definition, it's just that it has bad connotations. But if you want to add it as an answer you're more than welcome (as always).

Answer (score 7):

I would say that there's another more common that is a good fit.  ***[consultante](https://dle.rae.es/consultante?m=form)*** (que consulta [one who asks]),  which appears almost 10 times more frequently than *preguntante* (6559 vs 730) when checked at the same source [Hemeroteca Digital](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=consultante&f=text&t=%2Bcreation&l=600&l=700&s=0&lang=es)

Here is the RAE's definition of this (latin) verb:

> [consultar](https://dle.rae.es/consultar)
>
> Del lat. consultāre, intens. de consulĕre 'considerar', 'deliberar'.
>
> 1. tr. Examinar, tratar un asunto con una o varias personas.
> 2. tr. Buscar documentación o datos sobre algún asunto o materia.
> 3. tr. Pedir parecer, dictamen o consejo a alguien.

Answer (score 5):

The word [preguntante](https://dle.rae.es/preguntante) is in the DLE with this meaning:

> 1. adj. Que pregunta. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.

It does not seem to be a very common word, but a [search](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=preguntante&f=text&t=-creation&l=600&l=700&s=0&lang=es) in BNE's *Hemeroteca Digital* shows that it is indeed used sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

In my work in Latin America, in the Legal / Financial / Political sectors, we usually bifurcated the English word “asker” two ways into Spanish. When spoken, we generally used “Quien pregunta” or, “El / La  que pregunta.”

However, in writing or in a formal interaction (like a debate) we generally used “el / la autor(a) de la pregunta”. In Spain, they often seemed to use “el / la interrogador(a)”.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *preguntante* I would say *preguntador*, but imo *consultador/consultante* sounds a bit better. Anyways, I don't think there is any word used frequently to talk about that person, I think *Quien pregunta* is the best way to refer to him/her.

Answer (score 1):

Very much to my surprise I find in the dictionary https://dle.rae.es/inquisidor?m=form

> inquisidor, ra
> Del lat. inquisītor, -ōris.

> 1. adj. Que inquiere. U. t. c. s.
> 2. m. Juez eclesiástico que conocía de las causas de fe.

I had assumed that it only applied to the historical figure mentioned in definition 2 but but it seems I was wrong. Again.